# Confiabilidade e segurança das Sessions

Tags: php, asp.net, session

Estive lendo um pouco sobre [segurança com sessões](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/session.security.php) (tanto no ASP.NET, como em PHP), e li em alguns lugares que sessões, principalmente em PHP, podem ser facilmente roubadas (com facilidade ainda maior caso o sistema esteja sendo utilizado em rede local).

Visto que é prática comum (corrija-me se estiver errado) definir o acesso de usuários na sessão, quando fazem login no sistema, como posso tornar esse acesso mais seguro? Criptografar a sessão é válido? É uma boa prática de segurança manter dados diversos na sessão?

Comment: A session precisa de um identificador, quando não é passado por parâmetro, ele usa via cookie chamado `PHPSESSID`. Se você fizer o login em dois navegadores e trocar o valor desse cookie, já terá acesso a outra conta. No fim, sempre haverá um cookie mesmo trabalhando com session.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A *sessão* (padrão do PHP) é baseada na seguinte maneira:

- O cliente possui um identificador baseado em *cookies* (ou parâmetro de URL).
- O servidor possui um arquivo na pasta temporária, este arquivo possui "o conteúdo" da sessão.

Também irei dizer como mitigar isto, *caso seja aplicável*.

Primeiro entenda que o seu servidor gera um *cookie* contendo um identificador da sessão (*padrão o nome do cookie é PHPSESSID) e todas as requisições posteriores, dentro do website, vão enviar tal identificador.

---

### Vulnerabilidades comuns:

#### Packet Sniffing/MITM:

Um "atacante" vai fazer um MITM (man-in-the-middle) para obter este *cookie*, ele pode utilizar o DNS Spoofing (DNS Poisoning...), Proxy Attacks, ARP Spoofing...

O objetivo é o mesmo, no MITM é obter a sessão do usuário interceptando diretamente a conexão e "descriptografando" a conexão, se necessário e possível. *O MITM é um tipo de Sniffing.*

Modo de corrigir o problema:

- Utilize apenas TLS 1.2 (e 1.3) em todas as comunicações (não use SSLv2!).
- Utilize apenas *cookies* e nunca passe este valor por nenhum outro meio.
- Utilize o header de HPKP (HTTP Public Key Pinning) assim o navegador apenas confiará no seu certificado SSL.
- Utilize os *cookies* com as *flags* de `Secure`.
- Utilize os *cookies* apenas onde precisa, arquivos estáticos passe para um sub-domínio (`css.site.com`).
- Tenha cuidado com: manter a chave privada do certificado SSL em um local seguro.

#### Client-side attacks:

Sabe o famoso XSS? Então, ele também pode comprometer o seu website, fazendo com que um atacante crie um Javascript malicioso que capture os cookies do navegador, este é o caso "mais comum" de ataques XSS.

A ideia básica é obter no lado do cliente a informação do *cookie*, você não pode de fato proteger o usuário de todas as ameaças, por exemplo se o usuário estiver infectado com um malware, estiver utilizando uma extensão maliciosa ou estiver utilizando um navegador modificado "maliciosamente".

<sub>Casos mais e mais complexos permitem que o atacante faça o famoso ataque side-channel, [veja mais aqui](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.07373v2.pdf), isto PODERIA permitir a obtenção de tais identificadores de sessão.</sub>

Dentro de sua responsabilidade você pode:

- Utilize o *cookie* com o atributo de `HttpOnly` e `SameSite`, para impedir a leitura do *cookie* em caso de XSS e que o *cookie* seja passado para outro website.
- Utilize o atributo `domain` do *cookie* para apenas o seu domínio (sem incluir subdomínios!).
- Utilize o header de `X-XSS-Protection` e `Content-Security-Policy` para impedir que um código injetado por XSS se comunique com outro servidor.
- Utilize o atributo de `Integrity`, no HTML, para verificar se o `<script>` carregado dinamicamente não foi alterado por um código malicioso.
- Tenha cuidado com: redirecionamentos internos para link externos e filtre todos os dados recebidos dos usuários, para evitar XSS e não abra links usando `_blank`.

#### Predictable Token:

Isto é mais raro, ao menos que faça algum gambiarra. Isto ocorre principalmente por utilizar um gerador aleatório ruim, exemplo `/dev/random` ou CSPRNG que é oriundo de um "userspace CSPRNGs" ao invés do Kernel, como por exemplo utilizar o OpenSSL, [*com o seu MD5*](https://research.swtch.com/openssl) e [bugs no Debian Linux](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2008/05/random_number_b.html), como ocorreu com aplicativo de [Android que geravam carteiras de Bitcoin](https://arstechnica.com/security/2013/08/google-confirms-critical-android-crypto-flaw-used-in-5700-bitcoin-heist/) baseados em *Userspace random*... Particularmente não opte por *Userspace random*.

O ápice da previsibilidade seria:

- Gerar identificadores *sequenciais* como "1,2,3,4...", isso permite saber qual é o próximo identificador, assim facilitando acessar em outras contas.
- Gerar identificadores baseado no próprio e-mail/usuário.

Para corrigir isto gere identificadores aleatórios, CSPRNG:

- Utilize `/dev/urandom` (padrão do PHP 7.1+).
- Utilize longas strings (pelo menos 32 Bytes) para dificultar o *chute* de uma sessão.

---

**Geral:**

Considerações finais, caso priorize a segurança considere também:

- Gerar uma nova sessão (`session_regenerate_id`) para o mesmo usuário já conectado de tempos em tempos (ex. 5 em 5 minutos).
- Limitar o uso da sessão para apenas um IP em especifico (malefício: conexões instáveis vai "deslogar" a todo momento).
- Limitar o uso da sessão para apenas um navegador e geolocalização.
- Limitar a duração de uma sessão em poucos minutos de inatividade.

Se realmente quer segurança acima de tudo, considere também:

- Utilizar websockets ao invés de cookies.

Como um adicional:

- Exija a utilização de 2FA (ex. TOTP) para confirmação ações que podem comprometer a integridade da conta (ex. excluir conta, alterar senha, mudar e-mail, apagar publicação...).

---

Só para lembrar **não mencionei problemas que o seu servidor pode ter** em expor  o conteúdo das sessões, apenas indiquei problemas que podem expor o identificador da sessão. Por exemplo se estiver compartilhando o mesmo servidor (a maquina) com outras pessoas, ou seja várias maquinas virtuais, todos vão utilizar o mesmo cache da RAM e do CPU possibilitando ataques de side-channel. Em outros casos se o seu servidor tenha sido invadido, por qualquer forma, pode ler os conteúdos dos arquivos da sessão, normalmente localizadas em `tmp`. Além disso caso utilize o `exec()` ou `file()` baseado no input do usuário (e não seja tratado corretamente)  pode fazer com que o atacante consiga obter os arquivos das sessões (e seus identificadores).

Answer (score 1):

Não tem uma solução para autenticação que não utilize cookies. A Session do PHP é um cookie no navegador que fica guardado no `PHPSESSID`. Aí o PHP cria uma estrutura de dados correspondendo o valor da sessão com os dados que você guardou nela. Um `Session hijack` é quando você copia o valor do `PHPSESSID` de um navegador para outro.

Só que, para roubar a session, normalmente usam um ataque *man in the middle*, onde capturam a requisição do navegador antes de seguir para o seu servidor e, por consequência, o cookie vem junto. A única solução para resolver isso, é usando `HTTPS` na comunicação com o servidor, que mantém a requisição criptografada.

Não adiantaria criptografar a session, por que fica lá no servidor mesmo, mas também é importante não guardar dados sensíveis (senhas, informações pessoais) por segurança.

Comment: Somente HTTPS não protege de tudo.

Comment: Claro, mas ode dizer o que faltaria nesse caso?

Comment: Uma coisa que falta é utilizar a *flag* `Secure` e `HTTPOnly` no *cookie* para impedir obter o *cookie* por javascript, por exemplo, isto é o minimo a ser feito, além do HTTPS. Se isto não estiver sendo utilizado, mesmo em HTTPS, seria possível injetar um JS e coletar o *cookie*  por `document.cookie`, isto pode ocorrer por XSS e se não utilizar o `Content-Security-Policy` permite enviar tal informação para um servidor externo. Tudo isso usando HTTPS.